# When, if ever, are subsets elements?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

A very basic question on terminology that I have not seen addressed despite some searching: are any sets (such as subsets) considered elements? My understanding is that the empty set is a subset of all sets and it is not considered an element; is that because it is empty or because it is a set?

Comment: Read the _definition_ of "subset". Maybe that will clear up some things.

Comment: I do not follow your question.  A set is an object which contains elements.  For example the set $\{1,A,\color{blue}{blue}\}$ contains the element $1$, the element $A$, and the element $\color{blue}{blue}$.  A subset of a set is itself a set whose elements are all elements of the larger set.  For example $\{1,A\}$ is a subset of $\{1,A,\color{blue}{blue}\}$.  Now... elements themselves *can be anything*.  It is certainly possible for a set to be an element of another set, for example if in my running example that $A=\{1\}$ in which case $\{1\}$ is both an element and a subset of our set.

Comment: Most sets will not have $\emptyset$ as an element.  All sets however have $\emptyset$ as a subset.  That is not to say that *all* sets don't have $\emptyset$ as an element.  The set $\{1,\emptyset\}$ for example has the two elements in it: the first element being $1$ and the second *element* being $\emptyset$.  The subsets of $\{1,\emptyset\}$ are $\emptyset, \{1\},\{\emptyset\},\{1,\emptyset\}$.  Note that here we have $\emptyset$ as both an element and a subset of our set in question.

Comment: @JMoravitz Then again, I often work with ordinals, and  in that context, your "most sets" feels unfair

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are sets that have the emptyset as element, for example $\{\emptyset\}$ or $\{\emptyset,\text{dog},\text{cat}\}$. 
And $\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$ has both the empty set and my first example as element. Hoever, $\{\{\emptyset\}\}$ does not have the empty set as element; instead it has a single element and that has the empty set as element. We can build up arbitrarily convoluted nestings like this.